# How to export a vector graphic to eps?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have a Scalable Vector Graphic (svg) which I can convert to pdf with inkscape. The pdf still looks fine when viewed in okular or evince. However, I require an eps file. I understand that eps may contain vector data, but all I get is pixelated mess with a bounding box that is too small. Initially I tried the inkscape export feature to generate eps files. I also tried to transform the well looking pdf with `pdf2ps` + `ps2eps`, but I get the same disgusting results.

What am I doing wrong? How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: Are you saying that `inkscape -E` also rasterizes its output? Looking at the manpage it is probably due to ps lacking support for transparency.

Comment: EPS does not support all features from PDF/SVG, PS even supports less.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: I also tried --export-ignore-filters, which appears to be ignored. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Filters and transparency are not the same thing I guess.

Comment: neither pdf nor eps can handle grandients and eps does not support transparancy, IIRC. You will have to simplify your image so that all features can be represented using eps. Otherwise inkscape will always raster your image. What else is it supposed to do? After all that's the same routine used when printing ...

Answer (score 2):

This is the pseudo solution I used, now. My editor didn't seem to care whether to receive eps or tiff files, so I rendered all svgs with the target resolution and size, as it was impossible to get a decent result with eps files (as noted in the comments this is due to technical limitations of the eps format).

This can be done by opening the svg directly in `gimp`. It's a bit tedious to do this for several files manually, so a scripted solution would have been favourable, but well.